# Can't connect to Redis from Sinatra

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, redis, redistogo

I'm trying to hook up redis to a Sinatra app I'm building:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
#require 'sinatra/synchrony'
require 'redis'
require 'mongo_mapper'

require './startup'

def stats_connect
 uri = URI.parse('redis://redistogo:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@barb.redistogo.com:1337/')
 puts 'connecting to... ' + uri.to_s
 redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
 puts "Statistics connected >> OK" if redis
 return redis
end

stats = stats_connect

post('/') do
 #...
end
```

If I run the following app with foreman, I get this error:

- 18:09:02 web.1  | started with pid 825
- **18:09:08 web.1  |
  /Users/vladdypwnz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:113:in
  `connect_nonblock': Can't assign requested address - connect(2)
  (Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL)**
- 18:09:08 web.1  |    from
  /Users/vladdypwnz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:113:in
  `connect'

When I push to heroku, the error changes to this:

**/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/redis-3.0.1/lib/redis/client.rb:260:in `rescue in establish_connection': Timed out connecting to Redis on barb.redistogo.com:0 (Redis::CannotConnectError)**

If I pop into IRB, require redis and use the same exact stats_connect() method that I created, redis works just fine, I can access everything and create keys.

What's going on? I'm completely stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure your redis is running on barb.redistogo.com:1337?
A couple weeks ago I deployed an app using redis to heroku and used this configuration:

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
redis = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

to run it locally I did:

```
redis = Redis.new(:host => "localhost", :port => 6379)
```

Comment: Got it sorted - according to the logs it was trying to conect to barb.redistogo.com:0 because, as it turned out, URI parsed the address with port coming out as nil. Dunno why.